# Vue v-for how to use variable to acces JSON

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, vuejs2

I have this piece of html:

```html
<div class="home-cards flex-cards" >
            <div class="card border-info" style="width: 18rem;" v-for="name in equipment.data">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title text-info">{{name}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{equipment.name}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

And in my js file I have data stored as following:

```
      equipment:{
                data:[],
                paralel_bar: 'blabla',
                paralletes: 'blabla',
                rings: 'blabla',
                bar: 'blabla',
                bar2: 'blabla',
                weight: 'blabla',
                resistance_band: 'blabla',
            },
```

I fill equipment.data in an ajax call with strings like "rings", "paralletes", "bar".... randomly
As you can guess, the strings recieved on v-for="name in equipment.data" are the same objects I have stored on JS.

I want to use this 'name' to get the value of this objects like: {{equipment.name}}.
So if name == rings, when I do {{equipment.name}} it should acces equipment.rings and get the data stored there, but it does'nt work

Any tip on how could I achieve it?

BTW I'm using vue as cdn added on html

Comment: `equipment.data` seems to be an empty array. Try `v-for="name in equipment"`

Comment: Sorry.
I fill equipment.data in an ajax call

Comment: Sorry.
I fill equipment.data in an ajax call. And it gets filled with strings like "rings", "weight"... randomly. 
So once I make the ajax call, I want to acces to equipment.data to use this Strings to acces to the object properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `v-for`, you [should provide](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#key) a `key` attribute to the children elements. Also, in the template `equipment.name`, will simply access the string `name` property on `equipment`. To access the the variable `name` of `equipment`, you use the [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_accessors): `equipment[name]`.

A rewrite for your template:

```html
<div class="home-cards flex-cards">
  <div v-for="name, index in equipment.data" :key="index" class="card border-info" style="width: 18rem;">
    <div class="card-body">
      <h5 class="card-title text-info">{{ name }}</h5>
      <p class="card-text">{{ equipment[name] }}</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```